# Flask-Cors not working Nuxt + Flask (JWT used)

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jwt, cors

I have read all available solutions to my problem, still cannot figure out problem.

I have tried all available solutions, but cannot find anything helpful.

Whenever I send request, browser blocks request under CORS Policy.

My Flask App responds to OPTIONS call with code 308.

I have also tried adding `resources={r"*": {"origins": "*"}}` while initialising object.

I have also tried doing `app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'`

Nothing Works.

Backend:

```
from flask import Flask, make_response
from flask_cors import CORS

from tracer.blueprints.auth import app as auth_blueprint
from tracer.blueprints.url import app as url_blueprint

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint, url_prefix='/auth')
app.register_blueprint(url_blueprint, url_prefix='/url')

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return make_response('<center><h2>APIs hosted here.</h2></center>')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Frontend: (Nuxt Axios):

```
  context.$axios.setHeader('token', token);
  context.$axios.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
  const response = await context.$axios.$post(
    "http://127.0.0.1:5000/url",
    {
      redirect: url
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution. Thought I should share it.

Problem was, I was using `url_prefix` in blueprints, which led to problems in `flask_cors`. I suggest if anyone is having same problem,

remove `url_prefix` from `register_blueprint` and manually add url prefix in route definition.